# Full force refresh of continous aggregate view concurrently in TimescaleDB

Tags: timescaledb

Does TimescaleDB support the concurrent full refresh of continuous aggregate views? As this is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation. This would be similar as PostgreSQL materialised views `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`.

I am asking because there is some old stale data I need to refresh, but the normal [`refresh_continuous_aggregate()`](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/refresh_continuous_aggregate/#refresh-continuous-aggregate) is giving `canceling statement due to statement timeout`.

As a workaround, I increased the statement timeout, but that's a stop-gap fix.

Alternative if there are better ways to accomplish "rebuilding" on continuous aggregate data e.g. using PSQL scripting or simple iterative loops, I am happy to hear about those.

Comment: Have you tried shorter time intervals? Like using window_start and window_end with fewer days and executing them more frequently?

Also, I'd consider trying the new `timescaledb.finalized` to see if it performs better as several improvements were made in the new model, but needs Timescale 2.7.
Maybe also test if the real-time version works better instead of refreshing manually.

Comment: I have not yet tried shorter time intervals (I was secretly hoping there is a script for this lying around somewhere in Internet). I will also check Timesacle 2.7 new goodies.

Comment: What version of TimescaleDB?

Refreshing a continuous aggregate should only update the materalized data if something has been modified in the hypertable. For instance, if I refresh a month from a year or two ago, but no data has been invalidated, then that refresh should be "fast". But there was an issue in older versions of TimescaleDB that tracked invalidations multiple times causing the process to do more work than necessary.

This is different, BTW, from `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` which first generates the entire dataset and then does an `INSERT.... ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: Interesting. This is TimescaleDB 2.7.2. I will try to use shorter timespans and make a loop that calls `REFRESH` for the table in evenly spaced months to see if I can figure out something. Does the transaction isolation mode or any other connection settings matter for `refresh_continuous_aggregate() `? E.g. if there is a single "chunk" that happens to be large and something chokes on processing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a refresher loop that

- Uses Python and SQLAlchemy
- Figures out start and end date of a hypertable
- Calls `refresh_continuous_aggregate()` with fixed size slices from the start to the end
- Provides a nice [TQDM progress bar experience](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) telling when the job is likely done
- Each individual `refresh_continuous_aggregate()` stays under the SQL statement timeout

The refresh is not concurrent, though this could be easily achievable (assuming TimescaleDB can do two non-overlapping `refresh_continuous_aggregate()` at the same time).

Here is the Python code sample:

```py
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection, Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.testing.schema import Table
from tqdm import tqdm


def get_hypertable_range(
        connection: Connection,
        hypertable_name: str,
        timestamp_col="timestamp",
) -> Tuple[datetime.datetime, datetime.datetime]:
    """Get absolute first and last timestamps in a hypertable.

    Tested on prod. Takes ~1 min per query.

    :param timestamp_col:
        Timescamp column name. Assume naive UNIX timestamp.

    :return:
        Tuple (first timestamp, last timestamp)
    """

    sql = f"""SELECT * from "{hypertable_name}" order by {timestamp_col} limit 1;"""
    first = connection.execute(sql).scalar()

    sql = f"""SELECT * from "{hypertable_name}" order by {timestamp_col} DESC limit 1;"""
    last = connection.execute(sql).scalar()

    return first, last


def force_refresh_aggregate_iterative(
        connection: Connection,
        aggregate_name: str,
        start: datetime.datetime,
        end: datetime.datetime,
        slice=datetime.timedelta(days=90),
):
    """Iteratively force refresh continuous aggregate view.

    Assume the automated policy has missed data in the past, for reason or another
    and we need to rebuild the whole continuous aggregate.

    Call TimescaleDB `refresh_continuous_aggregate` in slices that
    are small enough not to hit any PSQL statement timeout issues.

    Display a progress bar using TQDM about the progress of the refresh.

    :param slice:
        How many days we force refresh once
    """

    assert start
    assert end

    cursor = start
    last_duration = None
    longest_duration = datetime.timedelta(0)

    days = (end - start).total_seconds() // (24*3600)

    with tqdm(total=days) as progress_bar:

        progress_bar.set_description(f"force_refresh_aggregate_iterative({aggregate_name})")

        while cursor <= end:
            # Add extra day to make sure we don't get odd missing hours somewhere
            # We don't mind overflowing at the end, because refresh_continuous_aggregate()
            # will just index empty days.
            cursor_end = cursor + slice + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            # Convert for PSQL strings
            slice_start = f"{cursor.year}-{cursor.month}-{cursor.day}"
            slice_end = f"{cursor_end.year}-{cursor_end.month}-{cursor_end.day}"
            logger.debug("force_refresh_aggregate_iterative() for aggregate %s: %s - %s, last refresh took %s",
                         aggregate_name,
                         slice_start,
                         slice_end,
                         last_duration or "-"
                         )
            # Execute refresh_continuous_aggregate() and time it
            start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            connection.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")\
                .execute(f"CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate('{aggregate_name}', '{slice_start}', '{slice_end}');")

            last_duration = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - start
            longest_duration = max(last_duration, longest_duration)

            formatted_time = cursor.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
            progress_bar.set_postfix({
                "Currently at": formatted_time,
                "Last refresh": last_duration or "-",
                "Longest refresh": longest_duration,
            })

            progress_bar.update(slice // (24*3600))

            # Move to the next slice
            cursor += slice


def force_refresh_aggregate_smart(
    session_manager: SessionManager,
    buckets: Tuple = (TimeBucket.m5, TimeBucket.m15, TimeBucket.h1, TimeBucket.h4, TimeBucket.d1, TimeBucket.d7, TimeBucket.d30,),
    statement_timeout="180min",
):
    """Do refresh_continuous_aggregate() in smaller slices.

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388687/full-force-refresh-of-continous-aggregate-view-concurrently-in-timescaledb?noredirect=1#comment129605333_73388687
    """

    with session_manager.connect() as connection:

        engine: Engine = connection.engine
        database_name = engine.url.database

        logger.info(f"force_refresh_aggregate_smart() for %s, statement timeout is %s", database_name, statement_timeout)

        start, end = get_hypertable_range(connection, "candle_ohlcvx")

        connection.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT").execute(
            f"SET statement_timeout = '{statement_timeout}';")

        for bucket in buckets:
            for name in long_list_of_aggregate_names:
                force_refresh_aggregate_iterative(
                    connection,
                    name,
                    start,
                    end
                )
```